# Explanation of tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding output_mode='multi_hot' behavior

Tags: tensorflow, keras, one-hot-encoding, multi-hot-encoding

## Question

Please help understand the definition of **multi hot encoding** of tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding and the behavior of `output_mode='multi_hot'`.

## Background

According to [What exactly is multi-hot encoding and how is it different from one-hot?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/467672):

> If you would use multi-hot-encoding you would first label-encode your classes, thus having only a single number which represents the presence of a class (e.g. 1 for 'dog') and then convert the numerical labels to binary vectors of size log2(5)=3.
> Examples:
>
> ```
> 'cat'  = [0,0,0]  
> 'dog'  = [0,0,1]  
> 'fish' = [0,1,0]  
> 'bird' = [0,1,1]  
> 'ant'  = [1,0,0]
> ```

## Behaviour of [tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/CategoryEncoding)

The document says `num_tokens` is the total number of tokens the layer should support.

> #### args
>
> ##### num_tokens
>
> The total number of tokens the layer should support. All inputs to the layer must integers in the range 0 <= value < num_tokens, or an error will be thrown.
>
> ##### output_mode
>
> - "one_hot": Encodes each individual element in the input into an array of num_tokens size, containing a 1 at the element index. If the last dimension is size 1, will encode on that dimension. If the last dimension is not size 1, will append a new dimension for the encoded output.
> - "multi_hot": Encodes each sample in the input into **a single array of num_tokens size, containing a 1 for each vocabulary term present in the sample**. Treats the last dimension as the sample dimension, if input shape is (..., sample_length), output shape will be (..., num_tokens).

According to the definitions of multi hot encoding above, I expected `tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=5, output_mode="multi_hot")` encodes 5 tokens into an array of size 3.

However, the document says "multi_hot" encodes each sample into **a single array of num_tokens size**, containing a 1 for each vocabulary term present in the sample, and behaves as such.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.constant(['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird']))

lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(max_tokens=5, oov_token='[UNK]')
lookup.adapt(dataset)
lookup.get_vocabulary()
---
['[UNK]', 'fish', 'dog', 'cat', 'bird']

mhe = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=lookup.vocabulary_size(), output_mode="multi_hot")
print(f"cat: {mhe(lookup(tf.constant('cat'))).numpy()}")
print(f"dog: {mhe(lookup(tf.constant('dog'))).numpy()}")
---
cat: [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
dog: [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
```

Which has no difference from One Hot Encoding.

```
ohe = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=lookup.vocabulary_size(), output_mode="one_hot")
print(f"cat: {ohe(lookup(tf.constant('cat'))).numpy()}")
print(f"dog: {ohe(lookup(tf.constant('dog'))).numpy()}")
---
cat: [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
dog: [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
```

For multi value inputs, multi_hot only handles the first value.

```
print(ohe(lookup(tf.constant(['cat', 'dog']))).numpy())
---
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

print(mhe(lookup(tf.constant(['cat', 'dog']))).numpy())
---
[0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
```

To handle multiple inputs, need to be 2D array.

```
print(mhe(lookup(tf.constant([['cat'], ['dog']]))).numpy())
---
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Apparently the definition of **multi hot encoding** of `tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding` is not the same with the one in [What exactly is multi-hot encoding and how is it different from one-hot?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/467672).

## Related

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/52892

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer here is that the explanation of multi-hot encoding that you linked to is not correct.

The purpose of multi-hot encoding is to create a one-to-one correspondence between categorical labels and places in the encoded tensor such that if there are multiple applicable labels than all would be included in a single input tensor. This is very obvious from your own example as quoted below:

> print(mhe(lookup(tf.constant(['cat', 'dog']))).numpy())
>
> [0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]

The output tensor is `[!UNK, !fish, Dog, Cat, !Bird]`

The description of multi-hot encoding you linked to is actually of a compact binary representation, a kind of encoding, but not one suitable for data science. Each input in the encoded tensor would have no specific meaning and it would be much more difficult for a traditional deep learning approach to derive the meaning from the input tensor.